# Download HLS ( HTTP ) Stream audio using python

Tags: python, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to download SoundCloud tracks using python and i was successful but i can't download HLS tracks so I'm here to ask for some suggestions and help

I'm using soundcloud-lib and here is the error:
As of soundcloud-lib 0.5.0, tracks that are not marked as 'Downloadable' cannot be downloaded because this library does not yet assemble HLS streams.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.